# MySQL Int Removes 0

Tags: php, mysql, integer

Hi I have got a column in my database which is set to Int.

But my data always starts with a 0 so whenever I add a new record, it strips the 0 off and I don't want it to do that incase the first character has to be a 1 at some point.

How can I overcome this issue?

Is the best way to use VARCHAR any then validate using PHP?

**Update**

If I enter 02118272 it is saved to the database as 2118272.

Comment: Could you please give an example of your data: what does it look like now and what you want it to look like?

Comment: This is a presentation issue, not a data issue.  You want to "present" your number 02118272, but the number is still 2118272.  You need to fix this in your user interface.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that you should use varchar type for that field. If you want to convert a variable to integer in php you can simply do this:

```
$var=preg_replace("/[^\d]/","",$var);
```

with this you delete all characters that aren't numbers and then you can put this value into the db preserving the initial 0.

Comment: -1 Storing the formatting of a number is only a good idea when the formatting might distinguish two values from each other. For example 01 is not the same as 1.

Comment: It's easier to use intval()

Answer (score 6):

The integer `7` is the same thing as the integer `000000000000000000000000007`.  They're both... ya know... seven.  When stored in the database, it's actually stored as something like `000000000000000000000000007` but most MySQL clients won't bother to show all those zeros.

If it's important in your application to show these numbers using a certain number of digits, you can add back as many leading zeros as you want using the `str_pad()` function:

```
str_pad($your_string, 10, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT);
```

Here, `10` is the length you want the string to be, `'0'` is the character that will get added on in order to make it that length, and `STR_PAD_LEFT` says to add characters to the left-hand side of the string.

If, on the other hand, the number `'007'` is fundamentally different than the number `'7'`, then you will have to use a `VARCHAR()` field to store it.  Those are no longer integers; they're strings with very different meanings.

Comment: It's not even stored in the database as a decimal number, so claiming it has leading zeroes in the DB is wrong.  That being said, the rest of this answer is the correct way of handling the issue.

Comment: Of course it has leading zeros in the database.  The number seven would be stored as `00000000000000000000000000000111`: a 32-bit integer with 29 leading zeroes.  Sure, they're not **decimal** zeros, but the concept is exactly the same.

Answer (score 3):

What you should be storing in your database is *data*. Formatting of that data is the responsibility of applications, not the database itself.

I would store it as an integer and, if you need that to 7 decimal places with leading zeros, the right place to do that is after extraction of the data to your application.